# Checking to see if two corresponding values exist in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am having an Issue at my job where I am to build a report that alerts subscribers if an employee has one task code for the day, but not the other. For example, If an employee has task code 2000 then they must also have a task code of 2010 or 2015 for that day.

the data in the database looks like this:

```
    fname | lname | empID | dateworked| taskcode
    ---------------------------------------------
    Jane  | Doe   | 09836 | 2018-10-1 | 2000
    Jane  | Doe   | 09836 | 2018-10-1 | 2000
    Jane  | Doe   | 09836 | 2018-10-1 | 2010
    Arch  | Bald  | 09825 | 2018-10-1 | 2000
    Arch  | Bald  | 09825 | 2018-10-1 | 2015
    Arch  | Bald  | 09825 | 2018-10-1 | 2000
```

I am not sure how I would be able to determine whether or not the employee has the correct codes, since they are all in the same column. I have tried to use t SQL However, I am very new to it. I would assume that there is a way to loop through the column, but I am unsure of how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional count. This select employees having 2000, but not 2010 or 2015 the same day

```
  SELECT empId, dateworked
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY  empId, dateworked
  HAVING COUNT( case when taskcode = 2000 THEN 1 END) > 0
     AND COUNT( case when taskcode IN (2010,2015) THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Use `> 0` on the second `COUNT` if want the employees having both codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query. It queries to get the empid where the emp has just one task code assigned to him. Let me know if this helps or you need explanation.

```
    create table temp
    (empid int,dateworked date, taskcode int)

    insert into temp
    values(09836,'2018-10-1',2000),
    (09836,'2018-10-1',2000),
    (09836,'2018-10-1',2000),
    (09825,'2018-10-1',2000),
    (09825,'2018-10-1',2015)

    select * from temp

    select empid,dateworked from temp
    group by empid,dateworked
    having count(distinct taskcode) = 1
```